# Blurry volumetrics in viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics, procedural

I am trying to make a procedural cloud. I followed a couple of tutorials, but every time I change to a volume shader, it gets blurry. This is the first time I'm messing around with this kind of stuff.

Is there a setting to control the blurriness? My first attempts went ok, but were also a little blurry on 2.83. I thought it might have been a version difference so I downloaded 2.9 but it is just as bad if not even worse.

[image: Attempt on 2.83]

*Attempt using Blender 2.83*

[image: Attempt on 2.9]

*Attempt using Blender 2.9*

None of the tutorials I watched looked like this. I saw some people having problems with the film lens but mine is at 1.5 (default).

**Q:** How to control the blurriness of the volume in the viewport?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Just to let you know: This is no regular forum rather a Q&A site so please always try to be specific in your title of the question which will make your question helpful to future visitors, I'd recommend read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and take the [tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Volumetrics is heavily reliant on lighting, so the first thing to do is to place lights accordingly. This is most easily accomplished by using [Rendered Preview](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/viewport_render.html) (shading tab uses Material Preview which uses it's own lighting by default), and to place a light close to your volume.

In addition to lighting, volume "crispness" can be controlled from the [Volumetrics section](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/volumetrics.html) of the *Render Properties* tab:

[image: Volume]

*Tile size* has the largest effect, however it also can also have the largest effect on performance. Increasing the number of *samples* will increase the detail, and shortening the end value will increase it further (bear in mind - the "end" value is related to your camera distance - too small a value and you won't see the volume except for at very close range.)